# Why is there a different font file for each @font-face?

Tags: css, fonts

I just saw the following css. Many combinations of font weight/font style are defined. Each with their own font file.

What is the purpose of this? Can't you just use the `font-style` and `font-weight` css attributes to customize your font for any given scenario? (Meaning you only need 1 font file).

Furthermore, how are ambiguous situations handled? For example, what if I use `font-weight: 300;` and `font-style: normal`. How will it know which font file to use? Afterall, there are many `@font-face`s that specify what should happen for`font-style: normal`.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(49c5f3e1-5867-4b1d-a843-2d07fa60d85d.f6a364902a8a8bdaa1fa.woff2) format("woff2"),url(f401df6f-54eb-406c-b46a-90b9451c598d.3dbdcd65208cb012bd8b.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url(62e28d52-436d-40b8-a5f0-00479f3f44ed.52fc2cd40de319afe9ce.woff2) format("woff2"),url(5b8c6fdc-0ba4-4b65-87e4-d5ae51245ea5.3a70873ee8763ff3bfc9.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(aad99a1f-7917-4dd6-bbb5-b07cedbff64f.d42bfc911f5d68722bc0.woff2) format("woff2"),url(91b50bbb-9aa1-4d54-9159-ec6f19d14a7c.7d6afb9bfc9ae3dda53b.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url(687932cb-145b-4690-a21d-ed1243db9e36.fee7f6b07451c77e66f0.woff2) format("woff2"),url(bc350df4-3100-4ce1-84ce-4a5363dbccfa.d5ffbc6688ebf0b1b882.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(2cd55546-ec00-4af9-aeca-4a3cd186da53.457e94a5b665614917d1.woff2) format("woff2"),url(1e9892c0-6927-4412-9874-1b82801ba47a.a17c827d23b2077f3be3.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url(7377dbe6-f11a-4a05-b33c-bc8ce1f60f84.2b7037ef717e05e19508.woff2) format("woff2"),url(92b66dbd-4201-4ac2-a605-4d4ffc8705cc.8d68084351a47c845fec.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(627fbb5a-3bae-4cd9-b617-2f923e29d55e.24932ad03d1891ed270a.woff2) format("woff2"),url(f26faddb-86cc-4477-a253-1e1287684336.6b04d1656ab054b0e3fe.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url(3f380a53-50ea-4a62-95c5-d5d8dba03ab8.b9a97cfb93014ba085a1.woff2) format("woff2"),url(8344e877-560d-44d4-82eb-9822766676f9.df8c3b28d539dc9ba7da.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirNext;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: none;
    src: url(14c73713-e4df-4dba-933b-057feeac8dd1.d8ee249af8ca02024e20.woff2) format("woff2"),url(b8e906a1-f5e8-4bf1-8e80-82c646ca4d5f.b8d9f485f998b3abda1a.woff) format("woff")
}
```